# R Equivalent of Python str.format

Tags: r, string-interpolation

For this code below ( in python) What is the equivalent code in R?

```
print("Sammy is a {}, {}, and {} {}!".format("happy", "smiling", "blue", "shark"))
```

Comment: I'm with akrun, the available options are `glue::glue`, `sprintf`, and `paste`/`paste0`, in decreasing order of safety and clarity (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways.  We may use `sprintf` from `base R`

```
sprintf("Sammy is a %s, %s and %s %s!", "happy", "smiling", "blue", "shark")
[1] "Sammy is a happy, smiling and blue shark!"
```

---

Or may use `paste/glue` considering these are objects created in the global env